# How to keep an Amazon ElastiCahe Memcached/Redis before a RDS MySQL database and use ElastiCache to cache the content?

Tags: amazon-web-services, java, node.js, amazon-rds, amazon-elasticache

I created one cluster in ElastiCache and connected that cluster with EC2 instance. And I want to include ElastiCache in front of my RDS(MySQL database). I have two questions which are as below.
1)Is there anything needs to be done from infrastructure side to implement above scenario?

2) Where I need to include the application(Java/Mean Stack applications) which will perform the actions checking Cache, querying the database, get the value, insert into the cache(I mean can I maintain these files outside my actual application/ should I include those details within the application?)

If there are any material/links, please share with me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should take advantage of the Heimdall Data Access Platform (HDAP).

> The Heimdall system is an intelligent query routing and caching data access layer that is installed in a distributed way on each **Amazon EC2** instance.
>
> Heimdall Data software packaging includes the following:
>
> > **Database Proxy for Amazon RDS**: Aurora, MySQL, SQL Server 2008+, PostgreSQL
> >
> > **JDBC Driver**: Gives access to Oracle and any other JDBC-compliant database
>
> For deployment, the only application-level change is to modify the host and port or JDBC URL to route through the Heimdall proxy/driver.

In proxy mode, there are two modes of deployment:

**Distributed mode:** A proxy resides on each Amazon EC2 application instance, for optimal performance.
[dist_mode_diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZ38f.jpg)

**Centralized mode:** One Amazon EC2 instance proxy services many application servers.
[proxy_mode_diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpAfo.jpg)

1. Depending on your current infrastructure you could choose Distributed or Centralized modes.
2. As for application level, you should be able to get by with modifying the host and port or JDBC URL to route through the Heimdall proxy/driver.

Read this article in detail as well, which should provide you some instructions on the setup: [Automating SQL Caching for Amazon ElastiCache and Amazon RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/automating-sql-caching-for-amazon-elasticache-and-amazon-rds/)